# Are all of the effects of a move canceled if the Label is locked and cannot be shifted?

Tags: powered-by-the-apocalypse, masks-a-new-generation

The Legacy's move *I know what I am* says:

> I know what I am: Once per scene, when you defend a teammate you can
>   shift Savior up and another Label down in addition to any other
>   benefits from the move, even on a miss. If you do, add 1 Team to the
>   pool.

What happens in the case that The Legacy has Savior locked? Is the whole move canceled or just the Label shift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Only the label shift is cancelled

The rules say this about locking labels:

> Pick one label and lock it - it  can't move up or down. If that Label would shift, ignore that effect in its entirety. (p 118)

What is unclear here is what the "effect" is in this situation. Luckily, the creator Brendan Conway has answered a similar question about the The Janus' second team move  which says:

> When you share a vulnerability or weakness with someone, tell them a
> secret about who you really are. Give them Influence, and shift your
> Mundane up and your mask’s Label down.

He was [asked](https://plus.google.com/+HansMessersmith/posts/86Y7n2k6YRP):

> If either Mundane or the mask label are locked, clearly you ignore the
> second clause.  But do you ignore the first as well?   Is the whole
> sentence the "effect" that is being ignored, or just the bit about
> shifting labels?

To which he replied:

> Just the Label shift! You get the benefits of the Label lock (no shifting Label), but the Influence is separate. Good question!

Extending it to the Legacy's move would bring us to the same conclusion. The Label shift would be canceled but you would still add 1 Team to the pool on a successful defend.

Comment: RIP Google+, home of the indie gaming scene.